# Define data at cell centers using VTK format

Tags: vtk, paraview

I would like to write a post-processor in order to open some flow field data in paraview (using vtk legacy format). I am fine with the mesh loading, but I have a question on the variables arrangement.

I need to put a value in every cell center and not in the cell nodes. Thus, I have one value for each cell and no way to have a value for each node. Do you know a way to fix this problem?

Thank you very much for your kind help

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but the vtk legacy format supports cell data, which is one value (skalar or tensor) per cell, see [vtk file format](https://www.vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf) page 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can specify cell data in the legacy ASCII VTK file format. Here's a simple example of a rectilinear grid with two cell data arrays with vector elements:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0

ASCII
DATASET RECTILINEAR_GRID
DIMENSIONS 4 2 2
X_COORDINATES 4 double
0.0 10.0 20.0 30.0
Y_COORDINATES 2 double
0.0 10.0
Z_COORDINATES 2 double
0.0 10.0
CELL_DATA 3
VECTORS first_array double
-1.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 1.0 0.0
1.0 0.0 0.0
VECTORS second_array double
-1.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 1.0 0.0
1.0 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: Hello Cory, thank you very much. I have to use unstructured_grid as grid type, but I suppose that the things a pretty much the same. I am going to try and get you back if I have some trouble.

Comment: Thank you Cory, that worked! I have another question for you, if you have time to answer. Is it possible to build a tetra (id=10) or  a wedge  (id=13) using an  hexahedron (id=12) ? I have already a post -processor which exports the data in tecplot format. Tecplot does not make any distinction beween the tree cell types, you just need to repeat the nodes to create a tetra for example. Would be great if the same thing can happen in paraview. Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question. You have a hexahedron and want to define a tet or wedge from it? You can create as many cells as you want even with the same nodes. Have a look at pages 9 and 10 of the linked VTK file format pdf for how to define the different cell types.